# eBay Shopping API for .NET?

Tags: .net, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I've been looking around trying to find a .NET release of the [eBay **Shopping** API](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/Concepts/ShoppingAPIGuide.html).
Is there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link you provided states:

> Supported Features
>
> Formats: XML, SOAP, Name Value, JSON
>
> Protocols: HTTP GET (REST) and POST"

It's a web service. You don't need a particular ".Net API". Just make a call to the webpage and handle the return value.

Example using information on [this page](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/FindProducts.html#Samples)

```
var xml = http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML&appid=YourAppId&siteid=0&QueryKeywords=harry%20potter&AvailableItemsOnly=true&MaxEntries=2&version=787
//parse the xml...
```

Of course you would need to use valid data. If you try using this as is you'll get an error xml response:

```
<FindProductsResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
        <Timestamp>2012-09-09T07:03:43.405Z</Timestamp>
        <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Application ID invalid.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>Application ID invalid.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>1.20</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Build>E789_CORE_BUNDLED_15285085_R1</Build>
    <Version>789</Version>
</FindProductsResponse>
```

However the whole point of this is that you send eBay some data via a query string and they return you xml.

This is the [url](http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML&appid=YourAppId&siteid=0&QueryKeywords=harry%20potter&AvailableItemsOnly=true&MaxEntries=2&version=787) used in the example above.